# Passing function name as an argument with its multiple argument in command line

Tags: python-3.x, command-line-arguments

I have 3 functions to calculate Nth Fibonacci number. I want to call a function from the command line passing multiple arguments.

Input: python3 a1.py fibr 5 10 15 20

Sample Output: 5:5 10:55 15:61 20:6765

I tried the below code:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    if sys.argv[1] == 'fibf'
        for i in range(2, len(sys.argv)):
            print (sys.argv[i], ':', fibf(sys.argv[i]))
    if sys.argv[1] == 'fibi'
        for i in range(2, len(sys.argv)):
            print (sys.argv[i], ':', fibi(sys.argv[i]))
    if sys.argv[1] == 'fibr'
        for i in range(2, len(sys.argv)):
            print (sys.argv[i], ':', fibr(sys.argv[i]))
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems here. The first is to call a function by name. The second is to prepare its arguments. To call a *local* function by name, look up a reference to that function through the dictionary of the local identifiers:

```
locals()[argv[1]](*argv[2:])
```

However, `sys.argv` consists of strings, and your functions expect numbers. The strings should be converted to numbers:

```
locals()[argv[1]](*map(int, argv[2:]))
```

So far, so good. However, if some parameters have to be numbers and some have to be strings, the situation becomes more complicated. Hopefully, your problem does not go that far.